# How efficient is .clone()?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a canvas area (nothing to do wth HTML5) where people can create "art" by dragging in photos, creating divs that they can drag, stretch, color, etc. etc. etc. The canvas div is inside a canvasContainer div. Now I'd like to implement an UNDO option.  My thought was to do a

```
                        canvasBackup$ = $('#canvas').clone();
```

when an operation began, say at every dragStart event, and at the end of the operation an UNDO, if asked for with Ctrl-Z,  would execute

```
                       $('#canvas').remove();
                       canvasBackup$.appendTo($('#canvasContainer');
```

My concern is that the clone, and perhaps the append,  might be a bit compute intensive as the page grows and start slowing down the page's responsiveness.  I suppose it depends on how jQuery does the clone.  If it just breaks off the section from the DOM and does a straight memory copy, it shouldn't be bad.  But if there's a lot of calculation and building going on it could be a problem.

Does anyone have a feel for whether this is a reasonable approach to implementing UNDO?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you already have a serialization format, so that you can save and send the drawings. Why not use this format ? Or actions ? Usually undo queues are done using a representation of the actions as storing the whole state of a document/image/etc is generally too heavy.

Comment: As an entirely practical matter, the only person qualified to say if this approach is reasonably performant is you or someone else who can test and profile the application. But it is obvious that this "undo whatever in just two lines" implementation is going to be among the slowest (if not *the* slowest) because it is totally dumb.

Comment: dystroy: The thing being generated here is pure HTML. There are no actual "drawings".  Serialization is something I would use to save everything to a server later, but here everything is staying at the client, so I'm not sure how serialization would fit in.

Comment: Jon:  Yes, it's dumb, but it's so elegant! Just getting a little bit smarter, trying to track what was actually done and all the states that changed, gets real complicated fast. So I want to make sure this isn't  going to work for me before going down that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every DOM modification you make triggers what is known as a [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)

During a reflow, the browser recalculates the position of every element.

If your DOM contains a lot of elements, and complex nested structures, reflows start to take more time.

Minimising the number of modifications to your DOM will help keep things responsive and fast.

On the javascript side, `Clone()` will clone an element and all contained elements.
this means that the deeper your structure is and the more child elements it contains, the longer it takes jquery to run through the hierarchy of the element it was called on.

The bigger it is, the slower `Clone()` will be.

Comment: Well, that's discouraging. But if everything triggers a complete reflow, doing a clone of the entire canvas shouldn't take any longer than, say, changing the width of a div. Also, is there something besides clone() that just goes in and "snip" 'snip' cuts out a DOM section and preserves it in a way that you can tie it back in later?

Comment: You could still use `Clone()` and `remove()`, just don't use it on the entire "canvas". Your best bet is to do what you tried to avoid, and track changes so you can do more precise "undo" operations rather than restoring the entire "canvas".
(that is a pretty confusing name for what it actually is)

Comment: Timothy, Jon:  I see they shut down our discussion, but I'll try to get my conclusion in here after working more on it. Clone() is not a 
good thing to use to implement undo because it kills the dragable and resizable attributes of everything you clone, so you would have to go back and try to add these back into every element on the page when you wanted to fall back and use the clone.  Worse, trying to make a cloned element resizable again seems next to impossible. Thanks for the discussion.